Getting ACF using statsmodels for a list of lags
I am able to use statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots.plot_acf to get a plot of the acf's for a specific list of lags, as the lags input accepts a list of values. I would like to have the raw data of the acf's, and thus want to use statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf, however this does not have a parameter lags. Instead, it seems to force me to compute the acf for all lags up to some value nlag, which is very inefficient for large data sets where I want to look at large lags. Is there a way to get the acf for a specific list of lags?

If time is a consideration, then calculate ACF only on sample of the data.

My dataset is 3 year timeseries, one row is 1 hour. So I just use plot_acf like this:
plot_acf(x=df_[var], lags=[0, 24, 24*7, 24*7*4, 24*7*4*12], ax=ax, alpha=0.05, auto_ylims=True)

Where 0 - lag 0, lag 24 - daily, lag 24 * 7 - weekly, etc.
